# What is the alternative for Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::hasNext?

Tags: php, mongodb

One of my application using MongoDB Client library with old php version.
I just upgraded my php version as well as upgraded  mongo library. 
When following function is calling, it's giving me

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::hasNext

```
function get_result_row () {

            if ($this->cursor->hasNext()) {
                return $this->cursor->getNext();
            }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Ask if method exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change for this:

```
/* $cursor now contains an object that wraps around the result set. Use
 * foreach() to iterate over all the result */
foreach($this->cursor as $document) {
    //Do here your logic or try
    //return $document; 
    print_r($document);
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php

Comment: Already tried, it's giving in fatal error on line 

`foreach($this->cursor as $document)` :

Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\LogicException: Cursors cannot yield multiple iterators